# Check if string starts with http or www or /

Tags: php, conditional-statements, strpos

This works:

```
    if (strpos($page, 'http') == 0) {
    $link = 'Test';
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
    if (strpos($page, 'http' || 'www' || '/') == 0) {
    $link = 'Test';
}
```

I need to return something if $page does not begin with any of those three: http, www, or /.

Comment: You can't pass multiple arguments like that with || you need to split them out into seperate strpos() calls and use the proper logical operator.

Comment: `strpos($page, 'http') === 0 || strpos($page, 'www') === 0`

Comment: Argh. It's not working. I've tried:
if (strpos($page, 'http') == 0 && strpos($page, 'www') == 0 && strpos($page, '/') == 0){
    $link = 'Test';
}

and I've also tried using ||. It's giving me test every time, even when $page DOES start with '/'.

Comment: It's not working with looking for the '/'. It returns 'Test' everytime, even when it does start with '/'. It does work with 'http' and 'www' though. Any ideas why '/' isn't working?

Comment: If the subject does not contain the search string, then it returns `FALSE`. Which is equal to zero. Read the warning in the [manual](http://php.net/strpos). This is one upsite to my regex answer: no gotchas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately PHP doesn't understand "If the door is red or green or blue". You have to spoon-feed it "if the door is red or the door is green or the door is blue". But there's still some shortcuts you can take:

```
if( preg_match("(^(?:http|www|/))",$page)) $link = "Test";
```

Comment: Wow, instant downvote. Usually I comment first and then downvote. I guess others don't bother with that.

Comment: The question was about PHP, your answer is Javascript. But I'm not the one who downvoted.

Comment: Right, I knew that. -facepalm- Fixed.

Comment: Trying yours now, Kolink.

Comment: Kolink, how can I make this NOT equal to. Right now it's working as equal to.

Comment: And thanks for downvoting a beginner who is only look for some help from experts. :)

Comment: Amal, thanks for that. That works! So thanks Kolink and Amal. Much, much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. You said "instant downvote," on your own answer(?), so I misunderstood you. But I'm all in good spirits. Thanks again.

Comment: Misunderstanding cleared up. Yes, I was referring to someone having downvoted my answer. Probably because I thought you were in JavaScript for some reason XD

Comment: I see what you meant now. I apologize.

Comment: Glad that's cleared up. Thanks again for the smooth, effective answer. Very happy.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (strpos($page, 'http') == 0 || strpos($page, 'www') == 0 || strpos($page, '/') == 0) {
    $link = 'Test';
}
```

you cannot use || like that.

Comment: If `$page` is `herpaderp`, then your condition will return `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the 'bad arguments' answers above, you've also got a serious logic bug. `strpos` can and WILL return a boolean FALSE if the 'needle' string isn't found in the 'haystack'. e.g.

```
$needle = 'foo';
$haystack = 'bar';
if (strpos($haystack, $needle) == 0) {
   echo 'found it!';
}
```

will say `found it!`, because strpos returned boolean FALSE, which PHP then typecast over to an int to compare to the 0. `(int)FALSE` becomes `0`.

You need use the strict comparison operator `===` to make sure you really are comparing int to int, and not int to possibly-boolean-false:

```
if (strpos(...) === 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using regular expressions for a case like this when you need to do pattern matching. More efficient in every way and way easier once you get the gist of it. This is a very helpful guide: http://oreilly.com/catalog/regex/chapter/ch04.html

Comment: Don't link without posting code. For all you know that server could blow up tomorrow and then your answer will be meaningless.

Comment: Thank you, however, I would not consider that appropriate as the guide is considerably extensive. O'reilly's server blowing up is a risk I will have to take.

Comment: You should at the very least take some useful quotes from that article and add them to your answer. That way, if it blows up, we'll still have some traces of what it was.